# Want to create NavigationDrawer on Imagebutton click

Tags: java, android

I am making a app in which I am using no action bar theme and now I want is that when I click on the Imagebutton then navigation drawer should be shown.

I have tried making drawer but don't know how to make imagebutton on click navigation drawer.

```
        <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:background="@drawable/backbutton"
         android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:id="@+id/backbutton"/>
```

No error bcuz I have not started anything please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `onClickListener` to the `ImageButton` that opens the drawer when clicked.
Something along the following lines should do the trick.

```
final DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ImageButton imageButton = findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
```